# RunOnUiThread created in onCreate(), when does it run

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

Just got some strange behaviour and needed to ask. My thought is that this `runOnUiThread` will run after `onResume()`

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // do stuff..
            // do stuff..
            ...runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Drink lemonade
                }
            });
        }
            // do stuff..
            // do stuff..
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
            // do stuff..
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
            // do stuff..
    }
```

Comment: I never looked in the docs, time to have coffee :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29):

> Runs the specified action on the UI thread. If the current thread is
>   the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately. If the current
>   thread is not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue
>   of the UI thread.

In my opinion you shouldn't call `runOnUiThread()` from the UI `Thread` because you already are on the UI `Thread`